# Angular5 ngAfterviewchecked , scrollIntoView()

Tags: angular

on page load, it should scroll down to a specific div I did that using below function, but the issue is after page load, its giving me issues while scroll up and down, the below function doesn't let me scroll up and down properly.

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void{

    if (this.primary){
      setTimeout(() => {
    this.scrollTo.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
      },100);
  }
  }
```

I didn't use timeout, so scroll was not moving from the div position. It was fixed there. But once I used setTimeout it start moving but still gives me issue. I just want to use scrollIntoView on page load.

Comment: what is `this.primary` ? you can use it to check for the `scrolIntoView` to be called only once and set the value of `this.primary` to false

Comment: I have a form and in form I have a button, and it should scroll up to that button, its like this < div class="form" *ngIf="this.primary"> < button #scrollTo class=....></button> </div> SO if it displays form then it should scroll to that buttton, if form is not there then it shouldnt'

Comment: oh ok . then u can add other variable which is true at the beginning and change it's value after `scrollIntoView` is called

Comment: I didn't get you, like var:boolean = true; ngif="this.var" run function... and this.var = false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a variable to prevent the function from being called multiple time

```
isStarting:boolean=true;
ngAfterViewChecked(): void{

    if (this.primary && this.isStarting){
      setTimeout(() => {
    this.scrollTo.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
this.isStarting=false;
      },100);
  }
  }
```

Comment: How to avoid hacky settimout? havent dound?